# Change a checkout billing field placeholder in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, checkout, placeholder

I'm trying to change the fields placeholder of "billing address 2" in the checkout page, using the following code:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_fields' ,  'custom_override_checkout_fields',9999 );

// Our hooked in function - $fields is passed via the filter!
function custom_override_checkout_fields( $fields ) {
   $fields['billing']['billing_address_2']['placeholder']="dssfsd";
   return $fields;
}
```

it changes only for a moment than return back to it's defualt value.
see the following video (10s):
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-qOZ67gFQ98

Answer (score 13):

The only way to get this is using `woocommerce_default_address_fields`, but it will change both billing and shipping placeholder for Address 2 checkout fields:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_default_address_fields', 'custom_override_default_checkout_fields', 10, 1 );
function custom_override_default_checkout_fields( $address_fields ) {
    $address_fields['address_2']['placeholder'] = __( 'dssfsd', 'woocommerce' );

    return $address_fields;
}
```

*Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme).*

Tested and works

---

Now if you want to change **only** the Address 2 **billing** field placeholder you will:

1. Unset default Address 2 field placeholder (for both shipping and billing fields)
2. Customize only billing Address 2 field placeholder
3. Put back shipping Address 2 field placeholder

Here is the code on two hooked function:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_default_address_fields', 'custom_override_default_checkout_fields', 10, 1 );
function custom_override_default_checkout_fields( $address_fields ) {
    // Remove labels for "address 2" shipping fields
    unset($address_fields['address_2']['placeholder']);

    return $address_fields;
}

add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_fields', 'custom_override_checkout_fields', 90, 1 );
function custom_override_checkout_fields( $fields ) {
    // Add custom billing "address 2" label
    $fields['billing']['billing_address_2']['placeholder'] = __( 'dssfsd', 'woocommerce' );
    // Put back shipping "address 2" label
    $fields['shipping']['shipping_address_2']['placeholder'] = __( 'Apartment, suite, unit etc. (optional)', 'woocommerce' );

    return $fields;
}
```

*Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme).*

Tested and works